# How to set a custom cursor in an SKScene? (XCode, Swift4, Spritekit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, mouse-cursor, nscursor

I want to use a custom cursor for my project. Now, using one of the system cursors in XCode is no biggie, i simply call:

```
NSCursor.crosshair() .set()
```

(just an example)

This works fine but then I try to set my custom cursor the following way:
(inside didMove: to View or inside sceneDidLoad(), it doesn't seem to matter which.)

```
let image = NSImage(named: "hand1.png")
let spot = NSPoint(x: 4, y: 8)
let customCursor = NSCursor(image: image!, hotSpot: spot)
self.view!.addCursorRect(self.frame, cursor:customCursor)
```

When I try to build I get an error in line 3 saying "unexpectedly found nil".

So then I changed the code to this:

```
let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile: "hand1.png")
let spot = NSPoint(x: 4, y: 8)
let customCursor = NSCursor(image: image!, hotSpot: spot)
self.view!.addCursorRect(self.frame, cursor: customCursor)
```

Now the project builds, but nothing happens. The cursor doesn't change.

I also tried these lines here:

```
NSCursor.init(image: image!, hotSpot: spot)
NSCursor.set(customCursor)()
```

Again, the project builds but the cursor doesn't change. What am I doing wrong here?

I tried to follow all the guidelines i could find but the Apple Documentation on cursor events is not much help since its heavily outdated and mouse related topics are generally very rare since most stuff is about ios. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you figure out why it's not working?

Comment: Nope but since my project is far from being released anytime soon I’ve decided to use a workaround for the time being: I hide the cursor and i create an skspritenode with my custom cursor image as texture and in my update function i set the location of the sprite node equal to the location of the mouse. It’s laggy and highly unsatisfying but the code actually does what it looks like it should be doing. I kinda like it when that happens…

Answer (score 1):

From the `NSImage(byReferencingFile:)` docs,

> This method initializes the image object lazily. It does not actually
>   open the specified file or create any image representations from its
>   data until an app attempts to draw the image or request information
>   about it.

As a result, the image is not loaded from the file when the `addCursorRect()` method is called. In fact, the image size is (height:0, width:0) as shown in the following.

```
if let image = NSImage(byReferencingFile:"cursorImage.png") {
    print("\(image.size)")
}

// (0.0, 0.0)
```

I suggest you use `NSImage(named:)` to create the image from a file:

```
if let image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("cursorImage.png")) {
    print("\(image.size)")
}

// (32.0, 32.0)
```

Also, `addCursorRect(image:,hotSpot:)` should only be called from the `resetCursorRects()` method. From the docs,

> This method is intended to be invoked only by the resetCursorRects()
>   method. If invoked in any other way, the resulting cursor rectangle
>   will be discarded the next time the view's cursor rectangles are
>   rebuilt.

`addCursorRect()` is an instance method of `NSView` and, for SpriteKit, the view is an `SKView` which inherits from `NSView`. Accordingly, you could subclass SKView, override the subclass's `addCursorRect()` method, and change the view's class (to our SKView subclass) in the Storyboard.

Alternatively, you can accomplish this by extending SKView and overriding the `resetCursorRects()` method. For example,

**For Xcode 9.3**

```
extension SKView {
    override open func resetCursorRects() {
        if let image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name(rawValue:"cursorImage.png")) {
            let spot = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            let customCursor = NSCursor(image: image, hotSpot: spot)
            addCursorRect(visibleRect, cursor:customCursor)
        }
    }
}
```

**For Xcode 9.2**

```
extension SKView {
    override open func resetCursorRects() {
        if let image = NSImage(named:NSImage.Name("cursorImage.png")) {
            let spot = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            let customCursor = NSCursor(image: image, hotSpot: spot)
            addCursorRect(visibleRect, cursor:customCursor)
        }
    }
}
```

**For older Xcode versions:**

```
extension SKView {
    override open func resetCursorRects() {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "cursorImage", ofType: "png") {
            if let image = NSImage(contentsOfFile:path) {
                let spot = NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
                let customCursor = NSCursor(image: image, hotSpot: spot)
                addCursorRect(visibleRect, cursor:customCursor)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Project Navigator with cursor image highlighted.

[image]

Comment: I tried subclassing / extending SKView but the line:

    if let image = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(„cursorImage.png“)

throws an error saying: „Argument labels ‚(_:)‘ do not match any available overloads“
I tried to extend NSImage.Name to no avail. (
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/80627)
If I use my old line

    image = NSImage(named: „cursorImage.png“)

I don’t get the error „unexpectedly found nil“ anymore but the image is still nil.

I think the problem is that for some reason the NSImage doesn’t get loaded or initialized or whatever.

Comment: I don’t know anymore!

I’m using XCode 9.3 so the code you originally posted should work, it just doesn’t.

Using the code „For older XCode versions:“ does the same: image = nil.

I’m probably missing something very obvious, I’m just too stupid to figure out what.
I even tried ludicrous stuff like downcasting NSImage.Name(string:) or NSImage(contentsOfFile:) or just getting the image to appear on screen, it simply does not happen!

Maybe they changed something between XCode 9.2 and 9.3?

Comment: Typically, the `NSImage` variable is nil because Xcode can't access the image file. Make sure the cursor image file appears in the Project Navigator (see pic at the bottom of my answer). To add an image file to the Project Navigator (PN), drag/drop a file from a Finder window to the PN or right-click in the PN and select "Add Files to ..." menu option and select the image file.

Comment: I made absolutely sure that NSImage can access the cursor-image-file but unfortunately that didn’t change anything. I even created a new project dedicated to this problem by following someone’s „complete idiot guide to XCode“ and guess what: It does NOT work. While I can easily apply my image to an SKTexture or Node the same can not be said about NSImage. Well, this is where I throw in the towel. Plain old pointer cursor it is. Anyway thanks for your help and patience, your answer still taught me something!

Comment: I updated my answer to include code that works with Xcode 9.3. You can add `rawValue:` to the 9.2 answer. Oddly, adding a space before the file name, for example `NSImage.Name( "cursorImage.png")`, works as well. This has to be a bug.